# Add new key into collection on Mongodb (ordered)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need to add a new key into my collection on MongoDB, but want to add it before other key, for example:

My Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd41934e82a4e79362f2a4a"),
    "name" : "Mercado Livre",
    "attached" : false,
    "consultant" : {
        "id" : null,
        "name" : null
    },
    "createdAt" : "2019-11-19 14:32:52",
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need to add a new field after consultant (update all documents), for example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd41934e82a4e79362f2a4a"),
    "name" : "Mercado Livre",
    "attached" : false,
    "consultant" : {
        "id" : null,
        "name" : null
    },
    "new_field" : "New Value",
    "createdAt" : "2019-11-19 14:32:52",
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In Mysql I uses something like

```
ALTER TABLE document
ADD [COLUMN] new_field VARCHAR(50) AFTER consultant;
```

Comment: I doubt to say it can be achieved in mongoDB's document, basically DB is denormalized - no guarantee that a field exists or exists at a particular position, as each document is like a JSON, I think unless you rewrite the document with  all needed fields(fields ordered as you like) you might not be able to do it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses JSON, and JSON object properties are unordered. There is no possible way to guarantee what order the properties are in, and it really shouldn't matter. What are you doing that requires them to be in a specific order? Even if you did get them stored in the order you want, there's no way to guarantee they'll come back to you in that order.

So the answer to your question is, quite simply, you can't.

Comment: I did that last time that I need to ordered, but I was not sure if this is not possible to do or not, thank you for your help @crispytoes!!

Comment: Only thing MongoDB does is it always places the `_id` field _first_.